# Self-hosted web service for file search

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, file-search

I am looking for a nicer way to search files on the local file system via a web service. This service has to be self-hosted.

I imagine it to look similar to Google: A very simple user interface. When the user starts typing, it is already searching.

Hard requirements:

- Free as in beer
- Free as in speech
- Plugin-system or otherwise easily expandable
- Tags: The user should be able to add tags to files
- Automatically detects new files and adds them to the index
- My data doesn't go to somebody else

Soft requirements:

- Python plugins
- Good documentation
- Extracts text from PDF documents
- Allow the user to create filters (to automatically add tags)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/)? I think it meets at least all of your hard requirements:

- [free and open source](https://www.tagspaces.org/faq/), although you can opt to buy a Pro version with more features, if you choose to,
- has some [extensions](https://www.tagspaces.org/extensions/),
- allows you to tag your files,
- "Automatically detects new files and adds them to the index" - I think it is a check,
- your data stays with you:

  > [The app is running completely offline, all your data is stored locally and is never sent to the network.](https://www.tagspaces.org/faq/)
- has some decent [documentation](https://docs.tagspaces.org/),
- allows you to [self-host](https://docs.tagspaces.org/selfhosting.html).

It is not 100% perfect, but maybe still worth a look.

Comment: I've just tried it. It looks very neat, but after ~1 Minute of using it, it froze. Always when I click on "show files with this tag". So I had a look and I can't recommend others to do so except if they want to dive into the source code.

Comment: Sorry about that, it seemed to have worked for me, hence my answer. If I find anything else, I'll let you know.